# The residue calculus

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I would like to ask if somebody know how to calculate the integral:
$\int_{|z|=\frac{2}{n}}\frac{z+1}{\sin(n^2z^2)} \ dz$.

It is my homework and I would like to dig out of it. We should use a book Complex Analysis
Authors: GAMELIN, THEODORE a chapter 7 residue calculus. But I don't know how to connect a theorem which is described there with these example. Please could you help me. Maybe if you know some other literature or you know how to calculate it. Maybe it is easy, but I totally don't know how to start. 
Thank you.

!!! New information.  I think that we should find a Laurent expansion. !!!

Comment: Without giving the answer, the fundamental idea is that you can compute the integral by studying the analytical behavior of the function in the region enclosed by the integration path. In this case, you can just find the poles of the function inside the $|z| = \frac{2}{n}$ circumference (hint: there are $5$ poles in this case), find the residues in these poles, add them up and multiply the result by $2 \pi i$ (we assume that the integration path goes anti-clockwise).

Comment: Thanks!!! I will try to compute it and put here the answer. I am really grateful for it. It doesn't look so hard. :)

Comment: Can I ask. If I find poles, you said that there are five poles. I forgot tp say that n=6 in my case. So I solve na equation: $z = \pm \sqrt \frac{k \pi }{36}$, But I thing that just zero lies inside the circle $|z| = 2/6$.

Comment: Notice that when $z^2 = \pm \frac{\pi}{n^2}$ you also have $\sin(n^2 z^2) = 0$.

Comment: Yes. :) So there are three poles in my dormitory.

Comment: Well, since we are in the complex plane, there are $4$ values of $z$ that satisfy $z^2 = \pm \frac{\pi}{n^2}$. Two for $z^2 = \frac{\pi}{n^2}$ and two for $z^2 = - \frac{\pi}{n^2}$.

Comment: Would you say if you know, how to compute a double pole? Because in a book there isn't a function sin anywhere, so it wil be reduced and the computation is easy. But here if I use a pattern, there will be

Comment: $\lim_{z - 0} \frac{d}{dz} ( (z - \sqrt \frac{\pi}{36})^2* (\frac {z+1}{\sin(36z^2)}) )dz$

Comment: I find that tgis is a result : $(z+1)csc(36z^2)$. But I totally don't know why, because I can't compute any poles. :(

Comment: You can check how to compute them here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Calculating_residues).

Comment: Thank you. :) It is exactly what I need, much more materials. But I don't see anywhere in this page how to compute a double pole. Do you thinq that I should do it much more generally? :)

Comment: I found out that a patter is: $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{d}{dz} ((z-z_0)^2 f(z))$

Comment: But because there is a sinus, there won't anything disappear and I haven't found similar example for $\sin$.

Comment: That isn't true what I have written. :) There aren't double poles, then the calculation will be easy. I will put here an answer soon. :)